# Clicking on minimap causes strange behavior

Tags: starcraft

I had to reinstall broodwar on my dad's computer. The game has exhibited some very strange behaviors.

First of all, the game randomly minimizes when i click in the lower right corner.

Secondly, whenever I click on minimap, it doesn't go to the correct place. Instead, it takes me to the lowermost part.

I know this is the Starcraft 2 minimap but it shows perfectly what I'm trying to demonstrate. For example, when I would click in the middle of the map it would take me to the mid-bottom. If i clicked top right it would take me bottom right and so on.

Has anybody else ever experienced this??

[image: what would happen if i clicked in the middle of the map]

I'm working on a desktop with a Windows 7. Turning off the Windows Explorer process does not help anything.

Comment: What operating system?  Is this a desktop or a laptop?  Does the computer have a touch screen?

Comment: thank you i edited to include it in the question. There is no touch screen. and all the other clicks work fine

Comment: Multiple monitors, or only one?

Comment: Try using https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: @Kyralessa It turns out that there is a tv connected by cable somewhere in the other room! I disabled that in properties and everything works fine!! thank you so much! Even though it seems obvious I wouldnt have figured it out on my own

Comment: @Xitcod13 - You should add that as an answer yourself :)

Comment: You'd better add and accept your own answer, or I will steal your rep by doing so myself.  >:-)